# How to define the secant method with the help of an stream in scala? Root Finding-computation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, square-root

I really need some help with defining the secant method in Scala. It has to be built of two functions, where the first functions signature

```
val secantStream:(Double, Double, Double => Double)=>Stream[Double]
```

Then, define another function that given a stream, computed with the first function secantStream, 
returns the first xn such that for a given 'e' , it satisfies
`xn -x1 < e`.

This is a convergence criterium.
This second function has four parameters, `x0`, `x1`, a function with signature `Double => Double` and a value ***e***.

Then, in order to compute the square root of 8 (i.e., find a zero of the function: `f(x) = x^2 - 8)`, we can use the following code:

```
val f2m8 : (Double => Double) = (x) => { x*x - 8.0 }
secantMethod(0,10,f2m8,0.00001)
```

Can anyone please show how to use streams in scala with the secant method?

Comment: It sounds like you want `.takeWhile(_ - x1 < e)` but it's hard to know for sure. You've provided too much excess detail and not enough pertinent information.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an assignment. Show us what you've tried, and ask specific questions. Right now, it's "gimmethecode" which is not appropriate here.